# Where is session data actually stored in a Node/Express application?

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis

Where is session data actually stored in an Express application? Is there some kind of built-in cache that Node is able to access session data from? Is the session data stored in memory? Is it often the case that developers will save session data to Redis?

Comment: You could take a look at the `express-session` source code, https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/session/session.js you can see how they actually store the session. Your second question is a bit hard to answer, its all depends on the requirement, of course, you can use Redis (or any data store for that matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no session data built-into Express.  There are external modules such as [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) that you can bring into your project in order to create a user session object for use within your Express application.

With express-session in particular, it has a built-in "not-meant-for-production" memory store (so session data is kept in memory and would not survive a server restart).   But, the store is a pluggable item and there are dozens of session store options as listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores).  These offer storage in all sorts of different databases (for persistent session storage). Take a look at the list for all the various session store options.  You can see session store drivers for common databases such as MongoDB, Microsoft SQL server, DB2, Mysql to things like Redis, to various memory-based stores, and then even some cloud-based stores.

So, you have a wide range of options.

> Is it often the case that developers will save session data to Redis?

Redis is a popular option if your specific requirements match what Redis is best at.  If you don't necessarily need permanent session storage, are going to run your server on some version of Unix and you have a clustered application that needs access to session data from multiple server processes (so an in-process memory store can't be used).

Smaller deployments that don't need long term persistence can use one of the production-ready memory-based stores.  Windows deployments would pick a database better supported on Windows than Redis.  If you are already using one of the supported databases, many will choose that database for sessions just to simplify deployment, administration, support and perhaps licensing (why add another type of database).

Comment: So sessions are often stored in persistent data stores like a database? Interesting, I thought that might not be the case since sessions themselves are temporary. I'm guessing the `express-session` module would be the only thing that reads or modifies that session data, and that it would take care of cleaning up expired sessions?

Comment: @GregThomas - It really depends upon what a given application is using session data for and how long it needs to persist.  For example, if a shopping cart is kept in a session, then you may want that to persist for weeks.  But, other types of applications, the session is entirely transitory and doesn't need to be in a database unless it needs to be accessed from multiple hosts (such as with clustering).